# "Handle/treat someone/something with kids gloves": translation variants and phrasing?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, comparaison-de-langues

I'm looking at the [translation](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/kid_gloves/590708?q=treat%20with%20kids%20gloves)s for the idiom [handle/treat (someone) with kids gloves](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/handle_with_kid_gloves) and I can see *manipuler avec des gants de soie, prendre des gants* (Wiktionary) and *prendre des gants avec quelqu'un* (Larousse en ligne) and I find the following [example](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prendre_des_gants) (from Wiktionary):

> Cet homme est très susceptible : il faudra prendre des gants pour lui
>   faire cette proposition.

So I gather in the example you could say "il faudra prendre des gants avec lui" using the pronoun to refer to "cet homme ([qui] est très susceptible)".

- Are *manipuler avec des gants de soie* and *prendre des gants (avec quelqu'un)* equivalent, are both used as often?
- Can you rephrase the example with the former using the pronoun like I did, is it phrased similarly to the latter?
- Can you phrase either like in English i.e. with the object after the verb: *prendre/manipuler quelqu'un/quelque chose avec des gants (de soie)*; which of the phrasing (the object after the verb, after the expression) is more common; is it typical for such expressions to accommodate both a direct and indirect construction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used nor heard *prendre avec des gants de soie*, only *prendre des gants avec quelqu'un*. Of course it doesn't mean it's never used... If I used it I would rather say *il faudra prendre cet homme avec des gants (de soie)* but *il faudra prendre des gants (de soie) avec cet homme/avec lui* sounds equally possible.

According to the *Dictionnnaire culturel en langue française* the phrase *prendre, mettre des gants* (avec quelqu'un) appeared in the 19th century. No mention of *gants de soie* either at *gant* or at *soie*.

Personally I hardly ever use *prendre des gants* mais *(ne pas) prendre avec des pincettes* to mean *handle with kid gloves".

Example from the *Dictionnnaire culturel en langue française*:

> « [...] c'est un maniaque, un braque, un pointu [...] un être susceptible, désagréable, insociable [...] à ne pas prendre avec des pincettes [...] » (E. Labiche, *Un monsieur qui prend la mouche*).

Thinking about it, it rather sounds like an antiphrasis used with that meaning (i.e. "handle s.o. with care"). *Prendre avec des pincettes*, in the affirmative [can be found with the same meaning](https://www.francaisauthentique.com/etre-a-prendre-avec-des-pincettes/):

> [...] une personne qui vous dit : « En ce moment, mon chef, il est vraiment à prendre avec des pincettes. » Ça veut dire : « Il faut faire attention, il faut prendre ses précautions quand on lui parle parce qu’il est très nerveux. » Prendre avec des pincettes, ça veut dire faire attention, prendre des précautions.

The first meaning of *(ne pas) prendre avec des pincettes* was:

> *Il n'est pas à prendre, à toucher, avec des pincettes* : il est très sale, répugnant, et, fig., misérable, ignoble. (1835) (*Dictionnaire culturel en langue française*)

> Il ne faut pas le pendre avec des pincettes.
>   Il ne faut pas prendre de pincettes avec lui.

*Prendre avec des pincettes* (affirmative then) when used for something and not someone means "to take something with a pinch of salt":

> Cette information est à prendre avec des pincettes.